# How do you Call a C# dll library in R

Tags: r

I have  a c# library and I want to call one of its function in R.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  I have already looked online and I have found nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See if the top-voted answer here will help. (The question title is slightly confusing; the main difficulty is in calling C# from R.)

[Is it possible to call a R statistics function to optimize C# function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214741/is-it-possible-to-call-a-r-statistics-function-to-optimize-c-sharp-function)